# Nuget with multiple nested solutions

Tags: nuget

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
/MyProduct
    MyProduct.sln
    /Web
        Web.csproj
        Web.Something.csproj
        Web.sln

    /Other
        Other.csproj
        Other.Something.csproj
        Other.Something.Else.csproj
        Other.sln
```

So there is one "overall" solution (that basically has references to web.csproj, web.something.csproj, other.csproj etc.....

Then, in each of the dir, there is a solution to manage that particular set of projects

My problem is with nuget.

If I open (for example) Web.sln and build, it works as expected, downloading the packages etc... storing them at the same directory level as Web.sln (in packages folder)

However, if I open MyProduct.sln - it stores them at the root (in packages folder)

Am I missing a step?

What should I be doing in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem would be solved by explicitly specifying the *repository path*, as described in the [NuGet Configuration Settings](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings), for all the solutions in your project structure:

```
<config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="C:\Temp" />
</config>
```

> Allows you to install the NuGet packages in the specified folder,
>   instead of the default "$(Solutiondir)\Packages" folder. This key can
>   be added to the NuGet.config file manually or using the NuGet.exe
>   Config -Set command.